# What are the parameters of transducer that I can get from an Anechoic chamber?

Tags: sound

I have a bunch of piezo elements, that I want to use as "Mics", for that I will test their reaction in a Anechoic chamber. My question is what the are characteristics that I can measure that describe those elements and can help me analysing the generated sound later, I already have in mind the following :

- Amplitude response
- Phase response

Thanks for any help in advance !

Comment: and why the down vote ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly frequency response as a function of the 3D direction of incidence. Also known as "polar pattern" or "polar balloon". You can also look at distortion and noise but that's more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you wanted to mount these, but definitely you should take a look at [**IEC 60268-4**](http://webstore.iec.ch/webstore/webstore.nsf/artnum/049787) standard (if you search net carefully you will find copy). Nevertheless parameters of your interest might be:

- Frequency response
- Sensitivity
- Directional pattern
- Front-to-rear sensitivity index
- Total harmonic distortion
- Equivalent SPL (EIN)